# is it possible to show the dump history of MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

Now I am using [Canal](https://github.com/alibaba/canal) to sync MySQL 5.7 -> MySQL 5.7 in different datacenter. The Canal would send a dump request to MySQL pretent as a MySQL slave node, Now I am not sure the dump is triggered or not, is it possible to show the master dump histroy?

Comment: According to the images on the landing page, Canal does not use `mysqldump` but instead reads MySQL's binary log. You would need to check on the primary server and the replicated instance whether there are any Canal-specific logs written in `/var/log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing in MySQL that stores `mysqldump` story automatically.

From the MySQL point of view, `mysqldump` is just another connection.